# New Install and No Internet Connection

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have an old dell laptop (Inspiron 6400) that I thought I would use Ubuntu 13.04 on.  I get no internet connect at all after I installed.  Wired or Wireless.  I am mainly just trying to get the wired connection to work first.

Here is the output for the ifconfig

```
lo   Link encap:Local Loopback
     inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
     inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
     UP LOOKBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
     RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
     RX bytes:9038 (9.0 KB) TX bytes:9038 (9.0 KB)
```

I went into the /etc/network/interfaces file and added the lines

```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I still get no internet after a reboot.

If I boot from the CD and use the try ubuntu option I then have internet.

Here is the output for the ifconfig from the CD boot.

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr: 00:19:b6:84:7c:5b
     inet addr:192.168.1.21  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255:255:255:0
     inet6 addr: fe80::219:b9ff:fe84:7c5b/64: Scope:Link
     UP BROADAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Mertic:1
     RX packets:1135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
     RX bytes:1029206 (1.0MB) TX bytes:119225 (119.2 KB)
     Interrupt:17

lo   Link encap:Local Loopback
     inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
     inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
     UP LOOKBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
     RX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
     RX bytes:22577 (22.5 KB) TX bytes:22577 (22.5 KB)
```

I could use some help getting the install package to work correctly

Comment: Keep those lines you added to your interfaces file and try disabling your network manager.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig -a` and `lspci -nnk | egrep -A2 '0280|0200'` from your installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Compare the outputs of dmesg (piped into less or saved in a file so it doesn't just fly by on the console) from boot and LiveCD boot looking for network stuff. Search for: For wifi "cfg80211","wifi","wlan0". For Ethernet "eth0". They may provide clues to someone on this forum as to what is going on.